# Where can I find archived night microphysics images from EUMETSAT? I

Tags: climate, remote-sensing, weather-satellites

I want night microphysics RGB composite from EUMETSAT. I'm looking for archived images. I tried finding them on EUMETSAT's data center page. Data from different channels of SEVIRI is available but composites are not. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think only the **Day** microphysics RGB composite is a standard EUMETSAT product. However, **the night microphysics RGB is available from other data portals** like the [ePort](http://eumetrain.org/eport.html) by [Eumetrain.org](http://eumetrain.org/). There you can access and visualize current or archive night microphysics RGB composites. The [Java version](http://eumetrain.org/ePort_MapViewer/index.html) works better for me, this is an screenshot of how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Camilo. I started using SatPy to create night microphysics images from IR images.